# "merit": countable vs uncountable

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

The word "merit" seems to be used as both countable and uncountable, in both single and plural forms:

- "there is no much merit" — 23k results
- "the claim has no merit" — 57k results
- "the claim has no merits" — 3k results
- "there is a merit in" — 382k results
- "there are no merits in" — 27k results

Is there any subtle distinction? Say, when someone asserts that someone's claim (more specifically, a court motion) is baseless, which form of "merit" — countable or uncountable — is more appropriate?

Comment: In the UK I think we mostly use the uncountable "the motion has no merit" or "there is no merit in the motion," though _merits_ is also heard, especially when something is "[judged] on its merits" or when exam results are mentioned: "six merits and two distinctions." "There is no much merit" is surely a typo: it should be "there is **not** much merit." "There is a merit in..." sounds somewhat old-fashioned or vicarly.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Mind posting as an answer? How about "there is **no** merit"? Is it not correct? If correct, why would the addition of "much" make it incorrect?

Comment: OK. Reposted as an answer. I had already talked about "there is no merit". I've now explained why I thought it was a typing error.

Comment: Google search results are not a very good indicator of whether a phrase is correct or common, due to quirks of how Google indexes things, the large number of non-native speakers on the Internet, and other factors.  You might find it more useful to use [Google Books](https://books.google.com/) or [Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams).

Comment: Also, don't forget that any mass noun can be used with the indefinite article if you mean "a specific type of X", like "They used *a* flour made from corn husks" or "The floor was covered with *a* fine gray dust" although this is an unusual usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the UK I think we mostly use the uncountable "the motion has no merit" or "there is no merit in the motion," though *merits* is also heard, especially when something is "[judged] on its merits" or when exam results are mentioned: "six merits and two distinctions."

"There is no much merit" looks like a mistyped "there is not much merit." We never say "**no much**". "Not much" is extremely common and useful. It means "only a little." "Not much whisky" means "only a little whisky."

"There is a merit in..." sounds somewhat old-fashioned or vicarly.